# create a storage class in objective-c

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

Hi I am trying to build a storage class for my iphone app. The storage class is for storing a list of food orders and each order has a food name and price. In the app, I want to store it in order into an array named orders when i press a button at my food menu.I am new to Objective-c,
and I am a Java user. What I want to build is a storage class which is similiar to java's ArrayList class, and  the myStorage class holds the food name and price.

I have build some codes already, but compiled with error "Local delcaration of 'order' hides instance variable' on my Storages.h at @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orders;

Storage.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Storage : NSObject{
    NSString *name;
    NSInteger *price;
}
@property (nonatomic)NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic)NSInteger *price;
-(void) setName: (NSString *) n;
-(void) setPrice: (NSInteger *) p;
-(NSString *)getName;
-(NSInteger *)getPrice;

@end
```

Storage.m

```
 #import "Storage.h"

 @implementation Storage


 @synthesize name;
 @synthesize price;


 - (void)setName:(NSString *)n {
     name = n;
}
 - (void)setPrice:(NSInteger *)n {
    price = n;
}
- (NSString *)getName{
return name;
}
- (NSInteger *)getPrice{
    return price;
}


@end
```

Storages.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Storage.h"
@interface Storages : NSObject{
    Storage *order;
    NSMutableArray *orders;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orders; // error "Type of property 'orders' does not match type of accessor 'setOrder'"

-(void) setOrders:(Storage *)order;
-(NSMutableArray *) orders;
@end
```

Storages.m

```
#import "Storages.h"

@implementation Storages
@synthesize orders;

-(void) setOrders:(Storage *)oneOrder{  

    [orders addObject: oneOrder];
}
-(NSMutableArray *) orders;{
    return orders;
}
@end
```

Comment: my storages.h  error still there, plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Java programmer, I can say that the closest to an ArrayList is an NSMutableArray. So you are doing fine in your Storage files.

The warning you are getting is because you are hiding infact the ivar (the class variable).

In this case it is fine to declare like this:

```
@interface Storage : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) name;
@property(nonatomic,strong) price;

@end
```

and then just synthesize those proprties in .m file.

The other error is just the same. When you create and @synthesized a @property, the compiler is going to write accessor for that props unless you provide your own, in this case you are providing your own, but the signature didn't much.

It is not quite the same, but it's like you had written in Java:

```
public void setOrders(List<Order> list) {
}


@Override
public void setOrders(Order order) {
}
```

And the jdk would stop you from doing so.

Also, very important, you have marked your question as iOS, then you do not have a garbage collector as it is in Java.

The benefit of using @property is that the compiler is going to write for you all the necessary lines of code for freeing the previous variable and assign a new value.

If you overwrite with your code, you are losing all those benefits and getting some memory leaks.

Comment: i did synthesized in storage.m

Comment: you are overwriting those variable in Storage. Just remove the setter and the ivar and you are fine.

Comment: @interface Storage : NSObject{
    NSString *name;
    NSInteger *price;
}
 in this case name and price are ivars, in Java they are called Instance Variable

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance variable that's called `order` already.  Rename your argument to something else, or rename your instance variable with an underscore `_order`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that you declared order as ivar and the functions parameter shadows it. My suggest is to don't user ivars at all, just properties. In your case this warning wouldn't hurt so much, just make sure you know which variable you're accessing. In this case you don't even access to the ivar, so you're fine.

I would remove all ivars and declare order as private property (in the .m file):

```
@interface Storages()

@property (nonatomic,strong,readwrite) Storage* order;

@end
```

Don't even synthesize it, it will be automatically synthesized to _order so you'll avoid the name conflict.